# PHP Define constant at different php file

Tags: php, laravel

I develop something for my assignment with PHP and laravel. I want to define some constants at a PHP file and use them at different PHP files.

For example

```
#App/config/constants.php

DEFINE('const1','something');
```

```
#App/Http/Controllers/userFolders.php

echo const1;
```

I tried to use require and namespace but they did not work.

Thanks for everything.

Comment: Have you included the `constants.php` file in `userFolders.php` script?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I did not use include, I thought we can use require. After you notice me, I googled with laravel include config file and found config('configfileName.php') function, and it works. Thanks for your helps...

Comment: As someone who has done this before, I strongly recommend you not use `DEFINE` for constants and instead just use configuration files and `.env` files.

Comment: @apokryfos I will use this constant as path of root directory and some custom directory. Should I .env ? Or I should use a php file for this situation.

Comment: Use a config entry e.g. create a file `config/myconfig.php` and add `return [ 'myconfigentry' => 'something' ]; ` then you can access it via `config('myconfig.myconfigentry')`

Comment: @apokryfos So many thanks, that is more usable. I edited my codes.